# Copy data in a row and spread them on separated columns

Tags: vba, excel, transpose

My row data is as follows:

```
Column A 
Datapoint1 
Datapoint2 
Datapoint3 
Datapoint4
```

I can transpose, but the result will be like this.

```
Column A   Column B   Column C 
Datapoint1 Datapoint2 Datapoint3
```

What I am trying to achieve is

```
Column A,   Column B, Column C, Column D, Column E, Column F, Column G 
Datapoint1, empty,    empty,    empty,    empty,    empty,    Datapoint 2
```

Datapoint 3 would appear in Column M. There are 5 columns in between.

There are about 3,000 Datapoints that need to be transposed into columns (separated by 5 columns in between).

Comment: Might be easiest to iterate through the values in ColumnA top to bottom inside a for loop, keep a secondary variable representing the column and increment that by 6 on each loop and then assign Cells(1,columnVar).Value = Cells(rowVar,1).Value. I don't believe there is anything built in to spread it out like you request. That or you could transpose first and then iterate across inserting cells. Either way its going to take a little bit to run, but if you turn off Application.ScreenUpdating before and turn it back on after, it will go a bit faster

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function below. I tested it with 3000 items and it ran almost instantly. The problem is after 2732 items, you run out of rows as the Excel maximum column number is **16,384** as of Office 2013 (see [Office 2010 Excel Specifications](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx) and [Office 2013 Excel Specifications](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HA103980614.aspx)). In the code below, once it passes that, it simply clears out the remaining rows and prints a statement to the debug window. Handle this how you want.

```
Sub TransposeIt()

    Const maxColumns As Integer = 16384

    On Error GoTo er

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False          '' shut off screen updating to speed up if possible

    Dim x As Range
    Set x = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)) '' Selects all cells until there is a blank
                                                 '' if you might have blanks, then calculate the last row manually

    Dim c As Range, col As Integer, val As Variant
    For Each c In x.Cells
        val = c.Value '' so as not to overwrite A1
        c.Value = ""
        col = (c.row - 1) * 6 + 1
        If col > maxColumns Then '' max number of rows we can actually use is 2732
            Debug.Print "Out of Columns, clearing Row " & c.row '' do what you want at this point
        Else
            Cells(1, col).Value = val
        End If
    Next

ex:

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

er:

    Debug.Print "An Error has occured: " & Err.Description
    Resume ex

End Sub
```